# How to call bloc inside initState method?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-bloc

I need to call the `fetchProfile()` method and get the `profileState.user` data in the `initState` method right after the page opens. Tell me, how can I write this correctly, how can I correctly call `Cubit` inside the `initState` method?

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      _emailDialog();
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

**cubit**

```
class ProfileCubit extends Cubit<ProfileState> {
  final UserRepository _repository;
  ProfileCubit(this._repository) : super(ProfileInitial());

  Future fetchProfile() async {
    try {
      final User? user = await _repository.me();
      if(user != null) {
        emit(ProfileLoaded(user));
      } else {
        emit(ProfileError());
      }
    } catch (_) {
      emit(ProfileError());
    }
  }
```

**state**

```
abstract class ProfileState {}

class ProfileInitial extends ProfileState {}

class ProfileLoaded extends ProfileState {
  final User? user;
  ProfileLoaded(this.user);
}

class ProfileError extends ProfileState {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the Readme of [flutter_bloc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc). There is a full tutorial and you can learn a lot.

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  context.read<ProfileCubit>().fetchProfile()
}
```

Wrap BlocListener for your widget tree. You can listen to ProfileLoaded state here and get the user data immediately.

```
BlocListener<ProfileCubit, ProfileState >(
  listener: (context, state) {
    // Do whatever you want.

  },
  child: Container(),
)
```

Comment: Can I then call ProfileLoaded.user in initState ?

Comment: No, you just interact ProfileLoaded state with UI(Widget tree). Why do you want to call in initState?

Comment: I want to receive data when the page is opened

Comment: I edited my reply. You can try BlocListener.

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to run the method `fetchProfile` directly when the widget (page in this case) will be built, I'd run the method when providing the bloc using cascade notation as such:

```
home: BlocProvider(
        create: (_) => ProfileCubit()..fetchProfile(),
        child: YourPageOrWidget(),
      ),
```

The `fetchProfile()` method will be called as soon as the Bloc/Cubit is created.

Note that by default, the cubit is created lazily, so it will be created when needed by a `BlocBuilder` or similar. You can toggle that so it isn't created lazily.

Comment: Can I then call ProfileLoaded.user in initState ?

Comment: You can, but it is not guaranteed that it is set. I would say that no you shouldn't? In initState you shouldn't (really can't) be depending on futures to be completed. You should rather let your UI display something else until `ProfileLoaded` state is set. This call: `await _repository.me();` in the cubit... it could take XYZ seconds, let's say 30 seconds... you shouldn't "lock" the UI then..

Comment: can you show me how to correctly select ProfileLoaded.user in initState so that I can use this value further.

Comment: I have tried if (state is PrifileLoaded) state.user.isEmail. But this condition was not met in initState

Comment: As I said, you shouldn't do that in initState. Use a `BlocBuilder` in the build method and react there based on state.